# Autofac: Get registration created by scanning

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I saw a couple of similar questions but no exact answer.

If I scan an assembly:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(...)
```

Can I then tweak the registration of a specific type that was registered this way?, i.e:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(...)
containerBuilder.GetRegistration<MyType>().WithParameter("param", paramValue);
```

Is there a way to achieve something of this sort with Autofac?

Comment: How many of your Types has special parameters (1,10,100,etc)? Does all your special types needs the same parameter (`paramValue`) or the paratmers are different (so MyType needs paramValue but MyOtherType needs otherParamValue?

Comment: There are a few types that need special treatment, and they need different parameters.

Comment: If you only have a few types then the easiest solution would be to register them by hand and use the `RegisterAssemblyTypes` feature for them...

Comment: I could but that beats the point of autoscanning - I'd have to repeat the settings that I set in the autoscan in the second registration rather than benefiting from the default. It's also very error prone because the second registration would take precedence so if the order is reversed the autoscan would overwrite the bespoke.
By few I meant 5-10 - not a trivial amount IMO and I expect it to grow over time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Except() method to exclude types from scanning, then you can register your special types by hand. More info on [Autofac wiki](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Scanning).

Comment: Yeah but then I have to a) explicitly exclude the classes in question, and b) re-register them. The whole point is to auto-scan the assembly with some defaults, then tweak a few registrations. For example when they have simple configuration primitive properties (base url, max/min, boolean flags etc). With Expect this becomes tedious.

Comment: @AmirAbiri Then, if you can programmatically define these "exception" types then you can add this logic to RegisterAssemblyTypes() construction, where clause for example. Could you provide more info please.